# How to transform list of indexed dataFrames to one DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dataframe

From the following dictionnary made of dataframes :

```
{0:     count  hashtag_id
17    540         397
8     432         329
44    385         996
15    360         392,
1:     count  hashtag_id
19   1100         996
13    869         592
20    600         996}
```

I want to learn how to create a DataFrame that looks like :

```
count   hashtag_id  user_id
540     397         0
432     329         0
385     996         0
360     360         0
1100    996         1
869     592         1
600     996         1
```

Can you help me achieve it ?

Comment: Did my solution work for you? Feel free to ask a follow-up question

Comment: @RakeshAdhikesavan, exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your dictionary is called `d`

First, append the user ids:

Iterate over the dictionary: For each DataFrame, create a new column called 'user_id' and assign the DataFrame's key as the value to the newly created column 'user_id'

```
for key,value in d.iteritems():
    value['user_id'] = key
```

Now concat all the DataFrames to create one Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.concat(d.values())
```

You might want to reset the index after doing the concat:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop = True)
```